# Postgres 9.4 Create Table if not exists like

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

This statement is throwing syntax errors:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "weChat_data_abc" LIKE "weChat_data_sample"
```

The table weChat_data_sample exists and is empty.

I get the error:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LIKE"
```

Output of SELECT VERSION():

PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn), 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I found the answer. Looks like I need to wrap the LIKE clause in parenthesis.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "weChat_data_abc"(LIKE "weChat_data_sample")

Documentation Here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Using quoted identifiers is almost always a bad choice. You should really avoid quoting identifiers, they are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need quoted identifiers since my tables are written in semi camel case.

Comment: As I said: don't do that, it's really not worth all the trouble (and the typing)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you give me an example of when this would be a problem?